# Pulling variable length substring from middle of string

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to grab variable length string from a primary string. 
Example:

```
ABC*12*1*name name****XX*123456789~
ABC*12*1*diffname diffname****XX*234567890~
ABC*12*1*diffname2 diffname2***XX*345678901~
```

I need to pull out the 'name name', 'diffname diffname', 'diffname2 diffname2'

etc from the string. And then replace the ' ' between the names with an asterisk  - but, I cant just insert in the first space in the string, there could be multiple names, and so I would want to insert the '*' into the second, or third space, depending on the length of the name string.

```
SELECT 
        CHARINDEX('*1*',data)+3 AS startpos,
        CHARINDEX('***',data) AS Endpos,
        data
from #t
where data like '%ABC*12*1*%'
```

This gives me a start point and end point for the variable length string. So I try:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(data,CHARINDEX('*1*',data)+3,CHARINDEX('***',data) -CHARINDEX('*1*',data)+3)
FROM #t
WHERE data like '%ABC*12*1*name%'
```

But this gives me

```
name n name aa*****X
```

as a result set, basically starting at the start point and then running well past the end point.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part is the problem :

```
SELECT .....-CHARINDEX('*1*',data)+3
FROM   .....
WHERE  .....
```

You want to substract with `Endpos` so it supposed to be written in brackets like so :

```
-(CHARINDEX('*1*',data)+3)
```

and if the brackets are removed the last part should become `-3` :

```
-CHARINDEX('*1*',data)-3
```